# How to access the data in the view list and make the display conditions with laravel-backpack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I would like to hide buttons in laravel-backpack (in list view) only if a certain condition is true.

This condition, I would like to do with a data one of my items.

For example, if the status of the article is "Published", remove the edit button.

But I can not access this data in my ItemCrudController.

What I would like to do:

```
public function setup()
{
  if(myData == 'published'){
    $this->crud->removeAllButtons();
  }
}
```

Do you have an idea of how? Thank you very much!

Comment: You have blade's `@if` condition for that purpose. Check on [example file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/views/welcome.blade.php) how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to create a few custom buttons and use those instead of the standard ones. It should be as easy as creating a few blade files in your resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons folder:
- edit_if_published.blade.php
- delete_if_published.blade.php

The files could just have your conditional and include the standard files from the vendor folder.

You’d then be able to remove the old ones and use the new ones in your setup() method: https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-buttons

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on the blade view section, you can try it this way.

```html
@if(myData =='published')

  {{$this->crud->removeAllButtons();}} 

   @else

   {{$this->crud->displayAllButtons();}}

@endif
```